# What does the -batch flag do in Emacs (or unix in general)?

Tags: unix, emacs

I just want to know the meaning of the "-batch" flag do in Emacs (or unix in general)?

I always use it when i do:

```
emacs -batch -l dunnet
```

And just now wondering what the heck its for lol.

Thanks

(*note: I'm not an advanced programmer so pls keep answers/comments 'simple' for me*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From tfm:

```
   The following options are useful when running Emacs as a batch editor:

          --batch Edit  in  batch  mode.  The editor will send messages to
                  stderr.  This option must be the first in  the  argument
                  list.   You  must use -l and -f options to specify files
                  to execute and functions to call.
```

See the [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BatchMode) for information about batch mode.

(There are really no flags that do anything in "unix in general").

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think I'm not smart enough to understand this tfm explanation. Can you "dumb it down" a bit for me?

Comment: It's for automating editing. If you don't want to automate editing, you don't need it.

Comment: I always need to type it to play dunnet and wonder why I needed it.

Comment: Ah, that's because dunnet uses emacs as a scripting environment instead of a text editor or operating system like sensible people.

Comment: [Some intelligent people disagree](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s05.html#id2948149) with your last point.

Comment: @JasonFruit: or that reinforces my point, since almost every switch has multiple possible meanings on that list. Hell, sometimes the same program has different switches on BSD and sys5-ish systems...